# Read only input in CakePHP 3.5

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

how to make an input box and datetime picker a read only in cakephp 3.5? I've tried to use the readonly and editable but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are here to help but you need to do your part. You need to show that you have taken some effort. You also need to provide code and a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use disabled instead of readonly

Comment: I've used that but it would not passed the data

Answer (score 0):

use `readonly` attribute like below -

```
echo $this->Form->input("name",array('readonly' => 'readonly'));
```